# Specific MessageBodyWriter for field

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

Say I have a data class in a JAX-RS 1 environment (RestEasy 2 with the Jackson provider) like this:

```
class Foo {
   int id;
   String name;
   Bar bar;

   ...
}
```

with `Bar` being:

```
class Bar {
   int one;
   String two;
}
```

Now I want to have `Bar` serialized in a special way (perhaps depending on the media type that was requested (or depending the phase of the moon), I would write a `MessageBodyWriter<Bar>`

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class BarWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Bar> {
   ...
}
```

which works very well if `Bar` is requested on its own like in

```
@GET @Path("bar")  
public Bar getBar() { return new Bar(...); }
```

But when I request `Foo` as in

```
@GET @Path("foo")  
public Foo getFoo() { return new Foo(...); }
```

the message body writer is ignored.

Now what I want is that this `MessageBodyWriter` is also used when I return `Foo` or a `List<Bar>`

I think the latter can be achieved by just writing a custom `MessageBodyWriter` for the `List` case, but for the former case I can't write a message body writer for all my application classes that contain a `Bar` field.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I was also trying to use a Jackson serializer on the `Bar` instance, but it looks like this is not even registered by RestEasy (and then, I think that way is too fragile anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not how message body writers work. The JAX-RS implementation will locate a writer, to be used in serialization, based on the type being returned from your resource method. So in your case, with a custom writer defined for `Bar`, with this resource method:

```
@GET @Path("bar")  
public Bar getBar() { return new Bar(...); }
```

the JAX-RS provider will serialize `Bar` using your custom writer. However for this resource method:

```
@GET @Path("foo")  
public Foo getFoo() { return new Foo(...); }
```

you do not have a custom writer defined, and serialization will be handled by the first matching (default) provider that can handle the combination of return class and content-type. A key thing to remember is that, unlike typical JSON and XML serialization libraries, JAX-RS entity providers are ***not*** recursive. Aka, for a given object `A` being returned in a resource method, the provider will attempt to locate a custom writer *only* for `A`, and not for any of the types included in `A` as variables.

Since you are using Jackson though, why not just define a custom serializer for your `Bar` class? That will handle pretty much every scenario you described:

```
public class BarSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bar> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Bar value, final JsonGenerator jgen,
            final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeFieldName("myBar");
        jgen.writeString(value.getTwo());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

You tell Jackson to use this custom serializer thusly:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=BarSerializer.class)
class Bar {
   int one;
   String two;
}
```

Lastly, don't forget that if you anticipate getting JSON back in the same form as you serialized, that you will also need a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonDeserializer.html).

To get it to work, you need the `jackson-mapper` and `jackson-jaxrs` jars in your classpath (and probably the `jackson-core` one as well).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. May pain point is obviously the non-recursiveness.
I was already looking into using a JacksonSerializer, but for whatever reason, this is not registered by RE for whatever reasons that I am still investigating.

At least I am not completely off-track :)

Comment: With RestEasy, make sure you actually have the Jackson libraries deployed with your code (in addition to the resteasy-jackson-provider library). I assume you annotated your beans with `@JsonSerialize(using=MyCustomSerializer.class)`.

Comment: Perception - interesting; will try that. Do you know if there is a minimum version of Jackson libs needed? Yes I annotated them that way.

Comment: @HeikoRupp - the `@JsonSerialize` annotation has been available since 1.1 release of Jackson.

Answer (score 2):

The JAX-RS runtime will only look up one `MessageBodyWriter` for the object returned by the resource method (see sectioin "4.2.2 Message Body Writer" in the specification), then that single `MessageBodyWriter` has complete control over the serialization of the entire object graph to be returned to the client.

In order to implement the behavior you wanted, you would need a custom `MessageBodyWriter` per media type, that is willing to delegate the serialization of a part of the object graph to another writer whenever it encounters a specific type in the graph, and then resume its own logic. Obtaining the delegate writer for the specific type wouldn't be a big problem (inject a  `javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` and call `getMessageBodyWriter()`), but I don't think the existing xml/json/etc serializers are implemented with such kind of extensions in mind, so I guess you couldn't just relay on them. Reimplementing an xml marshaller just for this is not an attractive option either.

Comment: At least I am only looking for this custom serialization for json :-) Thanks for pointing out that option wrt the delegation.

Answer (score -1):

Refer the below post for writing custom message body writer for your Java object's serialization.

http://h2labz.blogspot.in/2014/12/marshalling-java-to-json-in-jax-rs.html