# JAX-RS not working when custom realm is deployed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs, jaas

I had a working JAX-RS web service deployed on Glassfish 4.0:

```
@POST
@Path("authenticate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public XmlUser authenticate(@FormParam("email") final String email, @FormParam("password") final String password) {
    User user = getUserByEmailOrUsername(email, email);
    if (user == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return mapUserToXmlUser(user);
}
```

Then I deployed a custom realm and the web service stopped working, throwing the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class com.mycompany.api.XmlUser, genericType=class com.mycompany.api.XmlUser.
```

I suspect this has something to do with conflicting versions of Jersey, but I'm not sure.
In the web service war module I am using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the realm jar file I have to use the following (to be able to extend com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm) which I suspect, somehow, conflicts with the previous dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>glassfish-ee-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I undeploy the realm the web service starts to work again.

Edit:
If I deploy the realm without my JAXB class XmlUser (which is supposed to be used both by the web service and my realm, the client) the web service works again. But since the realm is supposed to use the web service for user lookup I have to have that class file included. This is what the generated JAXB class looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "email",
    "username",
    "password",
    "languageCode",
    "lastLogin",
    "userType"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class XmlUser {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Email")
    protected String email;
    @XmlElement(name = "Username")
    protected String username;
    @XmlElement(name = "Password")
    protected String password;
    @XmlElement(name = "LanguageCode")
    protected String languageCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "LastLogin", type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected Calendar lastLogin;
    @XmlElement(name = "UserType", required = true)
    protected String userType;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly states, it can't find a `MessageBodyWriter` for media type `application/xml` and class `com.mycompany.api.XmlUser`.

This means, Jersey (the JAX-RS impl on GlassFish) wants to send a message with a `XmlUser` object, but it doesn't know how to convert this object to XML (same would apply for plaintext and JSON).

There are different ways to solve this problem:

If your `XmlUser` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name = "XmlUser")` this should work out of the box. If you have this and get this error anyway, there may be some Jersey dependency which is missing.

You can provide a `MessageBodyWriter` for your `XmlUser` class. You basically have to implement the interface `MessageBodyWriter<XmlUser>` similar to this:

```
public class XmlUserMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<XmlUser> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(XmlUser user, Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(XmlUser t, Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> mm, OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    }
}
```

In the `writeTo` method you have to construct your XML and write it to the OutputStream `out`, here is a very basic example:

```
    @Override
    public void writeTo(XmlUser user, Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> mm, OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer = buffer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        buffer = buffer.append("id: ").append(user.getID());

        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(out);
        printStream.print(buffer.toString());
    }
```

You can find more details in the [Jersey docs chapter 7: JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html).

**See also:**

- [Specific MessageBodyWriter for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230192/specific-messagebodywriter-for-field)
- [MessageBodyReader/Writer for Generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779512/messagebodyreader-writer-for-generic-class)